# How to use Razor for Angular Template with prerendering

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, angular-universal, razor-pages

I'd like to use the power or Razor syntax in my Angular 4 views with server prerendering.  As I understand it from many past questions, doing this is trivial *without server prerendering*, but with the new built-in functionality for this in ASP.NET Core 2, it doesn't seem to work.  Is this even possible?

The error I get when executing is:

> Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module ".//Pages/Test"
>       at webpackMissingModule (---REMOVED---\Web\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:16250:87)

The way I tested this is by creating a ASP.NET Core 2 Angular app (via File -> New -> Project), then I opened fetchdata.component.ts and changed the templateUrl to '/Pages/Test'.  I created a very basic Razor Page at that address and made sure that if I open the browser to http://localhost:64066/pages/test, it loads correctly.

I tried a number of other variations on the URL, placing it in different locations, different names, etc, before I realized this appears to be failing in prerending, and it does make sense that this might not work.  So... how do I make it work?

*I'm sure some helpful people will wonder why I would like to use Razor syntax in my Angular templates.  That's been asked & answered on a number of other posts, so if we could kindly please skip that merry-go-round, that'd be swell.  Thanks!*

Comment: I am curious about the same thing, have you had any success? I did manage to find this [link](https://dyball.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/3-asp-net-core-angular-2-dont-waste-your-razor/) that was done in '16 so it looks fairly current maybe it will help

Comment: @AndyBraham At some point I think I moved away from server prerendering, but it was too late to come back to doing this.  So no, unfortunately.  A few things together removed 95% of my need to do this:  Typewriter (a Typescript templating tool) helped me get TS models from C# models without risk of typos in field names.  TS lacks a "nameof" operator like C#, but Google around and you'll find tricks.  Finally, I got really good at making Angular components and styling Boostrap with extends.  All of my form views have just one line of HTML per input field, so very they're very DRY.